# Stack bar chart for yes and no number of answers

Tags: r, ggplot2

It is possible to produce a stack bar chart with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

My case has 3 columns the category and the number of yes and no aswers as two separated columns.

I would like to create a graph like this but on for frequency.
What I mean in catA bar have the number of yes and no. The same for the other two categories.

```
category <- c("catA", "catB", "catC")
yes <- c(124, 50, 23)
no <- c(21,42,62)
df <- data.frame(category, yes, no)
```

How can I tranform the code?

As example output this:

```
library(ggplot2)
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08"), each = 2))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B"), times = 2))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

but without the year and have in x axis the label of every category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, this is quite easy to accomplish with the package `reshape2`, which can transform your data frame into a long format that can be used more easily with `ggplot2`:

```
df_long <- reshape2::melt(df, id = "category")

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = category, y = value, fill = variable, label = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

This is only a little different from your example output with the categories as x values instead of "2006-07" and "2007-08" (I assume you added this to make the code work?).